# Laravel / SSH permissions problems

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ssh, permissions

We have an in-house Ubuntu Linux server that we use for development of PHP sites. The /var/www folder is shared via Samba on our network with settings that force anything created through this share to be www-data:www-data. Not the best, but it works.

We've recently started using Laravel - and this requires you to perform commands through artisan on the command line. I SSH into the Linux server to do this - but as a different username. Any files that are then created on the command line via artisan have my username and group attached to them and therefore cannot be edited remotely through the Samba share as they don't have the correct permissions unless I then chmod / chown them as well.

I would prefer this to happen automatically or, even better, to not be needed at all. My colleagues will start to build Laravel sites soon and it's not going to look good if they have to do this.

I have a feeling I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with the way we've got all of this set up (aside from the www-data thing) - I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I would think using a version controlling system can sort the issue easily.

Comment: We have git monitoring the folder for version control purposes but the initial work to create the files is done via the command line. 

I SSH in, as "mikkyx" for example, run php artisan... to create the initial file (which is now owned by me), then try to edit it via the Samba share from my machine - which I now can't, as the file is owned by me but needs to be owned by www-data.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Apache or nginx?